# Can we redeploy only changed classes to a JAR over SSH

Tags: java, jar

I have an Android client/server program that I'm building using IntelliJ as my IDE.

The server, even for testing, runs on an EC2 host, as I work on my laptop in a variety of places and don't want to set up port forwarding everywhere I go!

I'm just wondering if there's a convenient way to redeploy my server code without having to resend all the libraries to make it a bit quicker.

I run my server as a .jar, i.e. java -jar Server.jar

Is it possible to, I dunno, have all the libraries in one jar and only send the compiled code?

aka.

At the moment I have just one jar:

Server.jar

But could I change it to two jars?

libraries.jar
server.jar

and I just reupload and run

server.jar

Can it be done?

*** UPDATE ***

Just realised I can easily achieve this by using

java -cp ./libraries.jar -jar server.jar

But I'll leave the question up in case someone else has the same mental hiccup

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Ok, **THE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK!** Something weird about the -jar command ignoring external libraries :S (so why allow the -cp flag ???!! Java is like democracy - the worst language except for all the others!)

However, this does:

```
java -cp server.jar:libraries.jar server.Server
```

Where server.Server is the Main Class

See [Accessing classes in an external Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393426/accessing-classes-in-an-external-jar?rq=1)

Comment: What's with SSH here?

Comment: I was just pointing out it's not a local machine, otherwise the IDE would handle it I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes very much possible, this is just like a patch.

You don't need to regroup libraries in a single jar (IF THEY ARE ALL THIRD PARTY).

As your deployment structure is already setup. So you just need to replace the part which you are changing.

Let's say you made some changes in class xyz of server.jar, then simply replace the server.jar with the new one and restart the server. The changes will reflect.

Comment: Ok, but how do I set it up with multiple jars? Maybe this is obvious... but at the moment it's just one jar, containing third-party libraries and source code

Comment: oh, right I can just use classpath... that's pretty daft of me!